# Why importing an Excel spreadsheet into SQL Server 2008 R2 would require Office 2010?

Tags: sql-server, excel, import

Per subject, attempted to import an Excel 2007 spreadsheet and prompted with "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 PROVIDER is not registered on the local machine" error, attempted patch, then encountered Office 2010 license key requirement, how come?

Thanks.